# How to post in a group on facebook using restfb?

Tags: java, restfb

I am trying to post a message onto a facebook group (I am the admin for the page). Here is the java code that I am using:

```
public void makeTestPost() {
        fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(groupPageAccessToken);
        counter = 0;
        fbClient.publish(groupID + "/posts", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", Integer.toString(counter) + ": Hello, fb World!"));
        counter++;
    }
```

with:

```
private final string groupPageAccessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private final String groupID = "XXXXXXX";
```

I got these values using the facebook graph explorer api online [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

But when I login to facebook I don't see any message/post on the group. Please tell me how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need an user access token with the permissions `publish_actions` and `user_managed_groups`.

Then you can publish a new message like this:

```
GraphResponse response = fbClient.publish(groupID + "/feed", GraphResponse.class, Parameter.with("message", Integer.toString(counter) + ": Hello, fb World!"));
```